# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection does not have a definition for CreateProxy

Tags: .net

i have referenced project to :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
```

but i get a and error which i wrote in the subject in the following line:

```
 private static HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatusMessageHubURL"]);
    private static IHubProxy statusMessageHub = connection.CreateProxy(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatusMessageHubName"]);
```

which dll is missing i have no idea,any help appreciated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change method HubConnection.CreateProxy to HubConnection.CreateHubProxy :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn433660%28v%3dvs.118%29